# CentOS - installing jdk

Tags: centos, yum

I run the command

```
yum search jdk
```

Output:

[image]

So I run `yum install ldapjdk.1686`
IT says: `No package ldapjdk.1686 available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pacakge is `ldapjdk.i686` not `ldapjdk.1686` (notice i not 1)